# Is there any way to customize interactions function of ant design charts?

Tags: charts, antd

I have tried to make function that highlight plot when mouseover event is triggered.
So I put interactions option 'element-highlight-by-x'.
[image]

First of all, it doesn't do anything.
I found that is doesn't work in svg render way.
So I changed renderer to canvas.
And it works well.

But there still was a problem.
Although I wanted to highlight if user mouse over plot's background area like default showing tooltip event, it only works when I put mouse on the bar(column).
[image]
And it always has black stroke. I want to remove this stroke, also.
[image]

Is there any way to handle it?

Thank you.